# angular 2 custom request method

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I need to consume an API with a custom HTTP Request Method.

In my case the HTTP Request method is "RELOAD".

In Angular 2 i have the list of Request Methods available in (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/enums.ts):

```
export enum RequestMethod {
  Get,
  Post,
  Put,
  Delete,
  Options,
  Head,
  Patch
}
```

If I make:

```
return this.http.request(url, {method: "RELOAD"})
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

I have this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid request method. The method "RELOAD" is not supported.

How can I send an http request with a custom request method?

Answer (score 1):

you can extend the http class like this.

```
export class CustomHttp extends Http {

  constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, options);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    //Starts
    return super.get(url, options).map(r => {
      //Completed
      return r;
    }).catch(//error handling);
  }
}
```

then use that class instead of html in your service, I hope it helps
*(you can do the same for request)*

Comment: I have already extended the Http class with a custom request, but I have to use a RequestOptions that need attribute "method" of type "RequestMethod".

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic request using ng2. using below code

```
this.objHttp.request("url.svc",{
      method:"POST"
    }).subscribe(data=>{

});
```

But problem is by default browser will not support Custom Methods. Can you please tell me the use case for using custom action method?

Comment: i need to use a CUSTOM http method: my method id "RELOAD". objHttp.request need a Request object with a "RequestMethod" method type

Comment: Browsers support custom methods! I have already done these kind of http request. The problem is that angular 2 has an "enum" of request methods available and enum is not extendible to other methods

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to use a custom method. Custom http request methods are compliant with RFC.
From https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html:

> The set of common methods for HTTP/1.1 is defined below. Although this set can be expanded, additional methods cannot be assumed to share the same semantics for separately extended clients and servers.

In angular 2 there is no way to use a custom method because the RequestMethod object is an "enum" and is not extendible.

I think I will open a issue on angular 2 github

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that `httpClient` changed lot after 4 years or not
I got same question when I want to use `MERGE` request to update my entity in Microsoft Azure Table Storage service recently.

```js
 let options: { body: any, headers: HttpHeaders } =
    {
        headers: this.generateDefaultHeader(...),
        body: payload
    };

    return this.http.request('MERGE',`${this.entitiesEndpoint}`,options);
```

just try to replace `MERGE` request into what you want.